# Matlab - distinguish overlapping low contrast objects in a RGB or Grayscale Image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filtering, detection

I have a big problem detecting objects within an image - I know this topic was already highly discusses in many forums, but I spend the last 4 days searching for an answer and was not able.

In fact: I have a picture from a branch (http://cl.ly/image/343Y193b2m1c). My goal is to count every single needle in this picture. So I have to face several problems:

Separate the branch with its needles from the background (which in this case is no problem).

Select the borders of the needles. This is a huge problem; I tried different ways including all edges() functions but the problem is always the same - the borders around the needles are not closed and - which leads to the last problem:

Needles are overlapping! This leads in "squares between the needles" which are, if I use imfill() or equal formula, filled in instead of the needles. And: the places where the needles are concentrated (many needles at one place) are nearly impossible to distinguish.

I tried watershed, I tried to enhance the contrast, Kmeans clustering, I tried imerose, imdilate and related functions with subsequent edge detection. I tried as well to filter and smooth the picture a bit in order to "unsharp" the needles a bit so that not every small change in color is recognized as a border (which is another problem).

I am relatively new to matlab, so I dont know what I have to look for. I tried to follow the MatLab tutorial used for Nuclei detection - but with this I just can get all the green objects (all needles at once).

I hope this questions did not came up before - if yes, I apologize  deeply for the double post. If anybody has an idea what to do or what methods to use, it would be awesome and would safe this really bad beginning of the week.

Thank you very much in advance,

Phillip

Comment: I'm not sure that you'll be able to have an answer. I can't even tell how many needles are on this branch, so for a computer...

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling - no chance. Well, maybe somebody has a nice idea, I will wait a while before I give up.

Comment: @PhillipG what is your actual goal ? There are a plenty of hidden (not only overlapped) needles, so you can't expect to be able to count them all. I guess there is some other purpose for what you are trying to do.

Comment: My goal is to see 1: the change of needlenumber in time, 2: compare the number of needles between different species, 3: get a clue how it could work to get more ideas :D I know it wont be 100% accurate, but since there will always some needles hidden (in every picture I take), it is consistent which reduces the mistake though..

Comment: @PhillipG the approach to do the first task can be very different from  the one asked. For instance, by "change in time" do you mean a photo would be taken from time to time to perform the comparison ? This can get harder if, for example, the illumination and positioning is not consistent. If it is, then it might be a lot simpler and related to image subtraction. For task number 2 I would, maybe (sorry, but details are lacking so I can't tell much), attempt to classify the species instead.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguishing overlapping objects is very, very hard, particularly if you do not know how many objects you have to distinguish. Your brain is much better at distinguishing overlapping objects than any segmentation algorithm I'm aware of, since it is able to integrate a lot of information that is difficult to encode. Therefore: If you're not able to distinguish some of the features yourself, forget about doing it via code.

Having said that, there may be a way for you to be able to get an approximate count of the needles: If you can segment the image pixels into two classes: "needle" versus "not needle", and you know how much area in your picture is covered by a needle (it may help to include a ruler when you take the picture), you can then divide number of "needle"-pixels by the number of pixels covered by a single needle to estimate the total number of needles in the image. This will somewhat underestimate the needle count due to overlaps, and it will underestimate more the denser the needles are (due to more overlaps), but it should allow you to compare automatically between branches with lots of needles and branches with few needles, as well as to identify changes in time, should that be one of your goals.

Comment: I had the same idea, unfortunately it is not that easy. At the beginning of the branch, the needles are more dense and a bit longer than at the end of the branch which would mean I bias my results a lot. But for a general estimation of "needles" and a change over time this is indeed a good solution. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jonas = you got yourself one HUGE problem.

Let me make a few suggestions.

First, along @Jonas' direction, instead of getting an accurate count, another way of getting a rough estimate is by counting the **tips of the needles**. Obviously, not all the tips are clearly visible. But, if you can get a clear mask of the branch it might be relatively easy to identify the tips of the needles using some of the morphological operations you mentioned yourself.

Second, is there any way you can get more information? For example, if you could have depth information it might help a little in distinguishing the needles from one another (it will not completely solve the task but it may help). You may get depth information from stereo - that is, taking two pictures of the branch while moving the camera a bit. If you have a Kinect device at your disposal (or some other range-camera) you can get a depth map directly...

Comment: I tried this (tips) during the day today but got to the borders of my understanding of image processing. The tips green as well I dont know how to count them.I though on: count pixels which are surrounded by X pixels of the color of the background, but this was not working. Do you have an idea how to start with this?I really like the idea with the stereoscopic pictures, but is it possible to get more information then? To do the pictures is simple,I just move the stative a bit for the second picture - but could you give me a start where to go from there? Thank you very much for the response :)

Comment: Use google to find. search terms should be "shape from motion" (you are trying to recover **shape** from motion of camera) "stereo reconstruction". Some examples I think you should look at are [here](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/demos/Stereo/Components/Stm.html) and this [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4576)